# Laravel 5.8, Auth::user() is not using User model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my User model which is called isAdmin, if "Admin" is set to 1 in the database, it returns true, if not it returns false.

How is this gonna work with `Auth::user()`?

When I do `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`, it returns `"Property [admin] does not exist on this collection instance."`

Thats why I came to the conclusion it may not use the User model?

User model

```
public function isAdmin() {
   if($this->admin == 1) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
   }
}
```

```
public function view () 
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            $user  = User::all();
            $post  = Post::all();
            $visit = Visits::all();


            return view('admin')->with('post', $post)->with('user', $user)->with('visit', $visit);
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
    }
```

Comment: use Auth::user()->isAdmin();

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped in my question. I am already using Auth::user()->isAdmin())

Comment: @CunnertA share the code from your `isAdmin` method, as obviously you are checking for a property to exist on a collection instance.

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Are you sure that the error occurs when you do this? Have you checked `dd(Auth::user()->isAdmin());` what is the result? As to me it seems like you are trying somewhere on `User::all()->isAdmin();`

Comment: If I do dd, it returns true, which is how it should be. But where could the error come from then?

Comment: Where else do you use the `->isAdmin()` check? Share that code

Comment: I have added the code where I try to check if the Auth user is admin

Comment: @CunnertA As you said `dd` is working fine then function `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` fine. 
So Make sure errors comes from this function or not. For checking remove `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` and see what occurs.

By the way you need to use `compact` method for return variable. Like `return view('admin', compact('post', 'user', 'visit'));`

Comment: Is the admin column in the database of type boolean? If that is the case, and for this use case, you can do without an extra function. You could just say Auth::user()->admin and it should work.

Comment: @CunnertA your problem is somewhere else, I bet in the view, and not using `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` as you tried `dd()` and it worked :) So the error says it all, trying to get property on a collection. I would like you to take a deeper look into my answer below.

Comment: @nakov I have seen your answer. But I have tested `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` in my project and it is working fine. Please tell me why this error occurs to "CunnertA"

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya sorry I tagged you by mistake, edited my comment above :)

Comment: @nakov No problem But can you explain about errors if you know

Comment: I do know, my answer below explains it, but @CunnertA does not care to look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may suggest, for this use case, you can actually make do without an extra function. You could just say `auth()->user()->admin`, specially if the 'admin' column in the database is boolean type.

Otherwise (even admin column is not boolean type) you can set up a mutator method in the model, like so:

```
public function getIsAdminAttribute()
{
   return (bool) $this->admin;
}
```

Then to check you can access it like so: `Auth::user()->isAdmin` or `auth()->user()->isAdmin`

And better yet, you might want to read about `Gate` and `Policies` to achieve more robust access controlling. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization

Comment: Calling `is_admin` or `admin` does not make a difference, the OP mentioned that wants to use a method :) + instead of casting it like that the OP can just add `protected $casts = ['admin' => 'boolean'];` in the model, it will achieve the same.

Comment: @nakov good catch. casts array is yet another method for casting and satisfies my main concern (first point) of having an extra method.

Comment: Anyhow `1 = true` and `0 = false` in PHP, so there is no need for casting unless the user needs to show `true` or `false` somewhere :) The error is really obvious, but the user gone away :)

Comment: Thank you! I have made it a bool and changed my method. So much cleaner :)

Comment: @CunnertA I really want you to teach me how this solved your problem that you've shared above :D

Comment: The issue was not the function but my blade view. I had a typo there. So your answer havent solved my issue, but it redirected me in a good and clean solution.

Comment: @CunnertA as I said in my answer below that your problem is in the blade view. But it wasn't typo, but you've used `$user->isAdmin()` and the `$user` is a collection. I am happy that you solved the issue, I just wanted to be clear that I am not missing something :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, change the code to just this:

```
public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->admin;
}
```

This code does exactly the same as you've got above..

Now in your `admin.blade.php` you are using:

```
$user->isAdmin();
```

But in the controller you have:

```
$user  = User::all();
```

which returns collection.

You should iterate over it, and check on each user instance if it is an admin:

```
$users  = User::all();
```

In the view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
 @if($user->isAdmin())
    {{ $user->name }} // some code here..
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

No Need To do anything just check if login then auth()->check() is return true then auth()->user() return the user

```
public function view () 
    {
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            $user  = User::all();
            $post  = Post::all();
            $visit = Visits::all();


            return view('admin')->with('post', $post)->with('user', $user)->with('visit', $visit);
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
    }
```

```
public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->admin;

    }
```

Comment: tbh I like the way of using a function, its much cleaner for me.

Comment: i change my answer.please check it

Comment: There's no need of `else` block here in the `view()` method as the `return` statement is used in the `if` block and the execution won't go to `else` if the `if` statement is true. If the `if` statement is false, the execution will jump to `return redirect()->to('/');` anyways.

Comment: i just repair his fuction & auth()->user()

Comment: @albus_severus The `else` block does not make any sense here. Because `the return statement` immediately terminates the execution of a function when it is called from within that function